# How can I send output to an external/second display in Java?

Tags: java, ms-office

I would like to be able to emulate the functionality of the "Presenter Tools" in MS Office.  This requires the program to be able to detect and use an external/secondary monitor/projector.

Could somebody please point me in the right direction for achieving this.

I would like to use Java 1.5

Thankyou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through the [GraphicsEnvironment](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html) class you can get information about the available screens on the computer.  In the docs for [GraphicsDevice](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html) there is a basic example showing how to get and use the screen information.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the GUI API you are planning.

For AWT, see John Meagher's post.

For SWT, you can look at Display.getMonitors() for a starting point.

Comment: GraphicsEnvironment is for Swing also, not only AWT

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, as I have only one screen... But I know the [Most Pixels Ever](http://code.google.com/p/mostpixelsever/) library: it is a Java library for [Processing](http://processing.org/), but I suppose it uses standard Java stuff to do that, the Processing part being only for easy interface.